# How to you check whether Hardhat is installed locally or globally. And how do you uninstall a global Hardhat installation?

Tags: hardhat

How do you check whether Hardhat is installed locally or globally. And how do you uninstall a global Hardhat installation? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if you are in a folder with a new project run : npx hardhat

and you see:

Hardhat version 2.9.3
Usage: hardhat [GLOBAL OPTIONS]  [TASK OPTIONS] etc.....

It means you have Global version.

Go to your home directory and just delete:
1.artifacts (folder)
2.cache(folder)
3.contracts(folder)
4.scripts(folder)
5.test(folder)
6.hardhat.config (file)
7.package(file)
8.package-lock(file)

Then again in the folder with your project run: npx hardhat

You should see capital letters HARDHAT
√ What do you want to do? · Quit....etc

its means you have hardhat running Locally.